# How to add condition to output in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have some information  that I retrieve through my models in my cshtml file which I would like the user to see. In my case I have some very long links which I would like shortened, so I added an if-statement to check the length and take a substring of it, but this doesn't work for me as there is no output on the browser.

In my code below, I cannot remove the if-statement, because there are cases where the string is shortner than 30 chars or an empty string.

How can I do this? MY code is pasted below:

```
@if (Model.Toxin[i].intake_link[0].Length > 30) { Model.Toxin[i].intake_link[0].Substring(0, 30); }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than do this, you could use a Razor helper.. these are relatively simple, just place this at the top of your file.:

```
@helper Truncate(string input, int length)
{
    if (input.Length <= length) {
        @input
    } else {
        @input.Substring(0, length)<text>...</text>
    }
}

Then you need only use it like this:

@Truncate(Model.Toxin[i].intake_link[0], 30)
```

If you want to make this reusable, you can do that too.. read more about this in ScottGu's article

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/asp-net-mvc-3-and-the-helper-syntax-within-razor

Answer (score 0):

```
@(string.Format("{0}", Model.Toxin[i].intake_link[0].Length > 30 ?Model.Toxin[i].intake_link[0].Substring(0, 30) : Model.Toxin[i].intake_link[0])
```

But I suggest you write some string extension and use it:

```
public static string TrimToMaxLength(this string value, int maxLength)
{
    return (value == null || value.Length <= maxLength ? value : value.Substring(0, maxLength));
}
```

and then use anywhere:

```
Model.Toxin[i].intake_link[0].TrimToMaxLength(30)
```

Comment: Okay but where do I put this method? In my controller class? or my model class?

Comment: You'll first need to create a very basic static class to house the extension method in. Then you would just need to either add a using statement within your View to allow you to access this extension method : 

`@using YourProject.HtmlHelpers;`

`@Model.Description.TrimToMaxLength(30)`
By the way you can google how to implement custom extensions method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use else

```
@if (Model.Toxin[i].intake_link[0].Length > 30) 
   { Model.Toxin[i].intake_link[0].Substring(0, 30); }
else { Model.Toxin[i].intake_link[0]}
```